# Why am I getting a "0.0" for an empty SQLite field in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, double

The code:

```
double indSRate[] = new double[c.getCount()];
indSRate[e++] = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("s_rate"));


if (String.valueOf(indSRate[s]) == null) {
    Log.d("Special Rate", String.valueOf(indSRate[s++]));
}
```

The field in the s_rate column was left blank by the user in an edit text field.  Am I somehow turning it into a double?

Inside of a loop, I want to do certain things if the field was empty, and other things if it is not.  But it seems to be either 0 or greater?  I can't test it being "0" or something different.  I HAVE to test between isEmpty or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the internal representation of a value is `NULL` and your query requests a `FLOAT`, you get 0.0 as the return value (see [this document](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)).

If you don't want NULL values for that column in your Cursor, specify that in your query. If you don't want NULL values in your database, specify that with a column constraint when you create the table.

Comment: I will accept your answer.  None of the answers really gave me the tangible code to solve the issue but you gave the correct reasons behind my mess up.  More importantly, your later suggestion got me on the right track.  I basically converted all the doubles to Strings.  And when the user submitted the EditText box--and if it was left blank--I made sure it was set to null.

Answer (score 3):

Primitive data types like double and int cannot be null or "empty"... When you convert these to a String the default values are "0.0" and "0" respectively.

**Addition**

You can check if double's value is `0.0`:

```
if(indSRate[s] == 0.0) { // default value
    Log.d("Special Rate", String.valueOf(indSRate[s++]));
}
```

or:

```
int rateIndex = c.getColumnIndex("s_rate");
while(c.moveToNext()) {
    if(c.isNull(rateIndex))
        Log.d("Special Rate", "Null");
    indSRate[e++] = c.getDouble(rateIndex);
}
```

There are many solutions...

Comment: The problem is not that double requires a value, it's that the API is not being used correctly.

Comment: Adding checks in your code and/or database will prevent future users from entering blank or otherwise invalid data. You can also update your current database to set all invalid data to some appropriate default value. Do either of the additions help your current problem?

Answer (score 2):

ResultSet.getDouble returns 0.0 if the value of the column is NULL. You have to explicitly check for ResultSet.wasNull() if you want to differentiate between 0.0 and NULL when using primitive doubles. Or, you can get ResultSet.getObject() and cast to a Double. In that case, you'll get a null reference which you can obviously check against 'null'.

Answer (score 1):

Double is indicating by 0.0 therefore it shows 0.0 when empty. Try this:

```
String s = null;

double indSRate[] = new double[c.getCount()];

indSRate[e++] = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("s_rate"));

if (String.valueOf(indSRate[s]) == null) {
    Log.d("Special Rate", s));
}
```